# How to retrieve only when all record in group by are correct(not some)

Tags: sql, oracle

For Example I have data as

TABLE PLAN

```
PLANNO    TYPE      QTY
A001      A       100
A001      B       201
```

TABLE ITEM

```
TYPE   BOX
 A     100
 B     200
```

I want to show the data only when all of the record QTY divide by BOX and have remaining as 0

my code right now is

```
    SELECT plan.PLANNO,count(plan.PLANNO) as TOTAL_ORDER  
FROM PLAN, ITEM  
WHERE PLAN.type = ITEM.type  
AND MOD(PLAN.qty,item.BOX) = 0  
GROUP BY plan.PLANNO 
 ORDER BY plan.PLANNO
```

my problem is my code is not confirm all of the record has a valid condition.
It is showing when at least one record are true.

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: For example In this case it should not display any result because the remaining of TYPE B is not 0

Comment: Is Correct on your sample data? Because they will be match on Type = A

Comment: Do you mean a mismatch does not match all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HAVING MAX(MOD(PLAN.QTY, ITEM.BOX)) = 0` (all mod() are zeroes):

```
SELECT plan.PLANNO , count(PLAN.PLANNO) as TOTAL_ORDER
FROM PLAN, ITEM  
WHERE PLAN.type = ITEM.type  
GROUP BY plan.PLANNO 
HAVING MAX(MOD(PLAN.qty, ITEM.BOX)) = 0
 ORDER BY plan.PLANNO
```

OR

```
SELECT plan.PLANNO , count(PLAN.PLANNO) as TOTAL_ORDER
FROM PLAN JOIN ITEM
ON PLAN.type = ITEM.type  
GROUP BY plan.PLANNO 
HAVING MAX(MOD(PLAN.qty, ITEM.BOX)) = 0
 ORDER BY plan.PLANNO
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05b3bc4/2)

Comment: thanks very much. it now worked for me I forget that we can use having max to to guarantee that add mod are zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT P.PLANNO,COUNT(P.*) AS TOTAL_ORDER
FROM PLAN AS P
  INNER JOIN ITEM AS I ON I.TYPE=P.TYPE
WHERE MOD(P.QTY, I.BOX) = 0
GROUP BY P.PLANNO
ORDER BY P.PLANNO
;
```